# What is the minimun faces that you need to make a polyhedron with all the faces equilateral triangles, but one(base) square? (not a Pyramid)

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I'm not a Mathematical person, but I know some things. I can't imagine a polyhedron with those characteristics. That polyhedron do exists? Is it possible to make something like that? (for that is why I ask for the minimum faces, I want to build it for my own)
I'm thinking something like a Icosahedron but with a square base.
I want to build something like that, but I can't find the form, or how I do that.
All right, I hope that this question wasn't in vain.
Thank you for reading, and thank you in advance if you can response

Comment: I think you can do it with $12$ triangles.  Put an equilateral triangle at each side of the base, as if you were going to make a pyramid.  Also put a congruent equilateral triangle with a vertex at each corner of the square.  At each corner lift the triangles up so that each side of the triangle at the vertex meets a side of each of a neighboring triangle along the side.  Now, by symmetry, the free sides of the "vertex triangles" form a square, and you can place four more triangles, as if you were building a pyramid, to close off the polyhedron.

Comment: you can do that by $10$ triangles, start from a triangular pyramid with square side faces, attach the square base of square pyramids to square side faces of triangular pyramid.

Comment: @achillehui You mean triangular _prism_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape mentioned by achille hui in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971422/what-is-the-minimun-faces-that-you-need-to-make-a-polyhedron-with-all-the-faces#comment6133532_2971422) is the smallest, needing 10 triangles.

---

Such a shape is necessarily a "[Johnson Solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_solid)," a (convex) non-uniform polyhedron with regular polygons as faces. Non-uniform just means that all the corners are not "the same", unlike a football (or soccer ball if you prefer), for example.

There happen to be only finitely many Johnson solids (92, in fact), and Wikipedia has the complete [list of Johnson solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Johnson_solids).

There are, ignoring the square pyramid, three such shapes made from equilateral triangles and a single square:

[Biaugmented triangular prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biaugmented_triangular_prism) (10 triangles)

[Gyroelongated square pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroelongated_square_pyramid) (12 triangles)

[Augmented sphenocorona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_sphenocorona) (16 triangles)

Comment: +1 ... OP *probably* wants convexity, but we should consider that the shape is not *necessarily* Johnsonian. I believe one can show that the only "smaller" polyhedra are: a square pyramid (4 triangles); a pyramid augmented by tetrahedron (6 triangles); a pyramid aug'd by two tets, either on opposite or adjacent faces (8 triangles). OP rejects the pyramid. The aug-pyramids may (or may not!) be disqualified for a notable (and notorious) geometric coincidence: some tet faces are coplanar with pyramid faces, creating *rhombuses* from pairs of triangles. (Also, the "adjacent" case is non-convex.)

Comment: Incidentally, we know the number of triangles must be even because of a standard argument. Suppose there are $n$ triangles, and the $1$ square. If we count the edges on each face ($3$ for each triangle, $4$ for the square), then we will have counted each edge of the polyhedron twice. Therefore, $$2(\text{number of edges}) = 3n+4$$ Thus, $n$ must be even.

Comment: @Blue Convexity is a big assumption that I totally took for granted, you’re right! I don’t think I’m in a great position to say much about the non-convex case, although you seem to be — I would welcome another answer, although I suspect you’ve settled it in the comments here :)

Comment: Wow. That was the answer I was searching for. Thanks a lot for answering!
I was looking for convexity, but it makes me happy that more answers are sought to the topic

Answer (score 2):

Expanding some comments into an answer.

@achillehui and @pjs36 have submitted the [biaugmented triangular prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biaugmented_triangular_prism), with $10$ triangular faces, as the minimal figure. @pjs36 shows that, under the not-unreasonable assumption of (strict) convexity, it *is* minimal. It's worth investigating non-convex candidates with fewer triangles.

---

First, some basic polyhedral arguments.

Suppose there are $n < 10$ triangles, and the $1$ square. (Note that, since each side of the square is connected to a distinct triangle, we have $n \geq 4$.) If we count the edges on each face ($3$ for each triangle, $4$ for the square), then we will have counted each edge of the polyhedron twice. Therefore, writing $e$ for the total number of edges,
$$2e=3n+4 \tag{1}$$
Consequently, $n$ must be even. Let's say that $n=2m$ (with $2\leq m \leq 4$), so that $(1)$ becomes
$$e = 3m+2 \tag{1a}$$
Now, *assuming* that the polyhedron is "topologally equivalent to a sphere" (a looser condition than convexity that nevertheless excludes self-intersections and other pathologies), we can invoke Euler's "characteristic" formula
$$ v - e + f = 2 \tag{2}$$
where $v$ is the total number of vertices, and $f$ is the total number of faces. By $(1a)$ and $f=n+1=2m+1$, this becomes
$$v = m + 3 \tag{2a}$$
The square "base" accounts for four vertices, so there are $x:=m-1$ (that is, $1$, $2$, or $3$) "extra" vertices. By the Pigeonhole Principle, at least two vertices must share a common extra vertex. Geometrically, equilateral triangles attached to a square base can only share an extra vertex located at the apex, $A$, of a square pyramid with that base. Let's consider cases:

- $x=1$. *All four* base-adjacent triangles share $A$. This is the *square pyramid*, which OP has dismissed.
- $x=2$. *Exactly three* base-adjacent triangles share $A$. This gives us a square pyramid with a triangular hole attached to a triangular "flap". Just two more triangles attach to the flap to cover the hole. This is a *square pyramid augmented with a regular tetrahedron*.
- $x=3$. *Exactly two* base-adjacent triangles share $A$; the other two triangles cannot share a vertex (well ... they *could* share the reflected apex, but I think we can reasonably exclude this scenario). If the $A$-adjacent vertices are attached to opposite sides of the square, then we have a square pyramid with two holes; if the $A$-adjacent vertices are attached to adjacent sides of the square, we have a square pyramid with a one large hole. In either case, we cover the holes with the four left-over triangles, and the two non-$A$-adjacent "flaps", to get a *square pyramid augmented with two opposite-or-adjacent regular tetrahedra*. (The "adjacent" case is non-convex.)

The augmented pyramids are subject to what I described as a "notable (and notorious) geometric coincidence": some tetrahedron faces end up being coplanar with pyramid faces, forming rhombus-shaped faces. The reader can decide whether a rhombus counts as a single (disqualifying) quadrilateral face, or as an acceptable arrangement of two triangles. (This ambiguity arose in a [1980 PSAT Exam question](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2015/07/19/this-psat-question-stumped-almost-everyone-attaching-a-tetrahedron-to-a-pyramid-sunday-puzzle/) about counting faces. The official answer counted triangles; a geometrically-savvy test-taker counted rhombi.)

---

Note: The (non-convex) *square pyramid augmented with three regular tetrahedra* ties the biaugmented triangular prism in being constructed from $10$ triangles, three of which are coplanar.

> Is there a *non-convex* polyhedron with $1$ square and $10$ *non-coplanar* triangles?

Comment: I did not even think about non-convex. But I haved a great time reading your answer! So, thank you very much (really) to take your time for writing this answer! I must say that I marked the pjs36's answer as correct, because I (just I) don't think that coplanar are different faces (let us say that to have 2 faces connected by a vertice together, they need to have different angle, if not, they are the same face).
I would love to see those non-convex polyhedron on a 3D model.
Thank you again.